# Automation script to modify WO created with createworkorder()

Tags: jython, maximo

Maximo automation script noob here. I'm trying to modify some values in a WO created with createworkorder(). I don't have any error in the logs, but the changes don't shows in the newly created WO. Can anyone help? Does my code make any sense? Thx.

Maximo 7.6.1 btw.

```
from java.util import Date
print "===================Print1 ==================="

woRemoteMbo = mbo.createWorkorder()

woset = woRemoteMbo.getThisMboSet()

print "===================Print2 ==================="

woRemoteMbo.setValue('WORKTYPE','ST')
woRemoteMbo.setValue('COMMODITY','')
woRemoteMbo.setValue('COMMODITY','EQ07031')
#woRemoteMbo.setValue('STATUS','ATTAPPRO')
woRemoteMbo.changeStatus('ATTAPPRO',Date(),'')
woRemoteMbo.setValue('WOPRIORITY','2')
woset.save()
```

Comment: The script is launching "after save"

Comment: I don't have time for a proper answer, but you could use MXServer.getMboSet() and the woRemoteMbo's WONUM and SITEID to load the new WO fresh from the database in an independent transaction. As a rule, unless you getMboSet() from MXServer, it is *not* your job to save() it. The behaviour you are seeing sounds like a save happened on woset before you got it, so your woset.save() is a second save without an intervening refresh() + fetch. It *is* your job to save() and close() independent MboSets.